# How I can build private Ethereum network with Ethereum 2.0?

Tags: eth-2.0

Hy @everyone , I am doing research on performance analysis of Blockchain in private network I have already done with Ethereum 1.0 using Geth. Now I want with Ethereum 2.0. How I can create private network with Ethereum 2.0

Comment: Interested in the very same topic.
Has anyone done that to a production stage? Thanks